# How can I add custom.css stylesheet to a JupyterLab Notebook for correctly rendering HTML/PDF outputs?

Tags: css, jupyter-notebook, markdown, jupyter-lab

For markdown, I use a software - Markdownpad 2. Here, I have a `custom.css` stylesheet that I specify in the application’s settings and I get perfectly rendered html and pdf outputs.

For jupyterlab notebooks, I primarily use VS Code and Azure Data Studio.

In a jupyterlab notebook, how do I change and use that `custom.css` to style my notebook as in rendered HTML/PDF outputs?

My primary concern is to define the default display font for HTML/PDF exports and have the markdown `text-align: justified`.

I have managed to get the HTML render sort of working by using `.jupyter/costum/custom.css` with the content of this CSS being:

```css
/* RESET
=============================================================================*/

html,
body,
div,
span,
applet,
object,
iframe,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
a,
abbr,
acronym,
address,
big,
cite,
code,
del,
dfn,
em,
img,
ins,
kbd,
q,
s,
samp,
small,
strike,
strong,
sub,
sup,
tt,
var,
b,
u,
i,
center,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label,
legend,
table,
caption,
tbody,
tfoot,
thead,
tr,
th,
td,
article,
aside,
canvas,
details,
embed,
figure,
figcaption,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
output,
ruby,
section,
summary,
time,
mark,
audio,
video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}

/* BODY
  =============================================================================*/

body {
    font-family: Input, 'InputSans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.6;
    color: #333;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 20px;
    max-width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: justify;
}

body>*:first-child {
    margin-top: 0 !important;
}

body>*:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}

/* BLOCKS
  =============================================================================*/

p,
blockquote,
ul,
ol,
dl,
table,
pre {
    margin: 15px 0;
}

/* HEADERS
  =============================================================================*/

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
    margin: 20px 0 10px;
    padding: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

h1 tt,
h1 code,
h2 tt,
h2 code,
h3 tt,
h3 code,
h4 tt,
h4 code,
h5 tt,
h5 code,
h6 tt,
h6 code {
    font-size: inherit;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 28px;
    color: #000;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 26px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    color: #000;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 24px;
}

h4 {
    font-size: 22px;
}

h5 {
    font-size: 20px;
}

h6 {
    color: #777;
    font-size: 18px;
}

body>h2:first-child,
body>h1:first-child,
body>h1:first-child+h2,
body>h3:first-child,
body>h4:first-child,
body>h5:first-child,
body>h6:first-child {
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
}

a:first-child h1,
a:first-child h2,
a:first-child h3,
a:first-child h4,
a:first-child h5,
a:first-child h6 {
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
}

h1+p,
h2+p,
h3+p,
h4+p,
h5+p,
h6+p {
    margin-top: 10px;
}

/* LINKS
  =============================================================================*/

a {
    color: #4183C4;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

/* LISTS
  =============================================================================*/

ul,
ol {
    padding-left: 30px;
}

ul li> :first-child,
ol li> :first-child,
ul li ul:first-of-type,
ol li ol:first-of-type,
ul li ol:first-of-type,
ol li ul:first-of-type {
    margin-top: 0px;
}

ul ul,
ul ol,
ol ol,
ol ul {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

dl {
    padding: 0;
}

dl dt {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 15px 0 5px;
}

dl dt:first-child {
    padding: 0;
}

dl dt>:first-child {
    margin-top: 0px;
}

dl dt>:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

dl dd {
    margin: 0 0 15px;
    padding: 0 15px;
}

dl dd>:first-child {
    margin-top: 0px;
}

dl dd>:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

/* CODE
  =============================================================================*/

pre,
code,
tt {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: Input, InputMono, monospace;
}

code,
tt {
    margin: 0 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

pre>code {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    white-space: pre;
    border: none;
    background: transparent;
}

pre {
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 19px;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 6px 10px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

pre code,
pre tt {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
}

kbd {
    -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
    -moz-border-left-colors: none;
    -moz-border-right-colors: none;
    -moz-border-top-colors: none;
    background-color: #DDDDDD;
    background-image: linear-gradient(#F1F1F1, #DDDDDD);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    border-color: #DDDDDD #CCCCCC #CCCCCC #DDDDDD;
    border-image: none;
    border-radius: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    font-family: Input, InputMono, monospace;
    line-height: 10px;
    padding: 1px 4px;
}

/* QUOTES
  =============================================================================*/

blockquote {
    border-left: 4px solid #DDD;
    padding: 0 15px;
    color: #777;
}

blockquote>:first-child {
    margin-top: 0px;
}

blockquote>:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

/* HORIZONTAL RULES
  =============================================================================*/

hr {
    clear: both;
    margin: 15px 0;
    height: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: none;
    background: transparent;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #ddd;
    padding: 0;
}

/* TABLES
  =============================================================================*/

table th {
    font-weight: bold;
}

table th,
table td {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 6px 13px;
}

table tr {
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #fff;
}

table tr:nth-child(2n) {
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
}

/* IMAGES
  =============================================================================*/

img {
    max-width: 90%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Unfortunately printing this HTML to PDF does not preserve the formatting very well with awkward pagebreaks, non-justified markdown text, etc. So

Answer (score 1):

I followed a suggested approach by creating a `custom.css` in the folder `./.jupyter/` exactly as I posted above in the Question.  It did not work. So as per another suggestion, I prefixed every CSS element with `div#notebook` . This, more-or-less, solved the problem. After 2 days and update operations - e.g., `coda update anaconda` - it broke down again. This time, I removed all the `div#notebook`  prefixes, and it kind-of work again.

I ended up combining both forms in a single `./.jupyter/custom.css`. That seems to more-or-less work so far.

The HTML output is not justified, however the PDF output is sorted-out. One big problem is that in TOC, the number and text kina get garbled when the heading text is too long.

Since the PDF output was my primary concern here, I would consider this issue as *approximately-resolved*. Although, I hope I knew what change in 2 days that I had to change that `custom.css` file and drop the `div#notebook`  prefix.

I should mention that the best option so far was to utilize Jupyter Books as in using the `jupyter-book` package. This is somewhat at the experimental stage, however, especially on a Windows system with PDF output.

Comment: Thank you!!, you saved me day an a half. I had `#toc-wrapper ` in my custom.css, and wonder why it wasn't working. With `div#toc-wrapper ` worked right away. :-)